# Como puedo enviar una props tipo objeto con Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Mediante map recorro un array de objetos y los envio a un componente hijos pero uno por uno los valores del objeto. Quisiera enviar todo el objeto pero no pude encontrar la manera de que typescript me lo permita.
Tengo este componente padre que tiene un state contacts que tiene un array de objetos:

```
function Contacts() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState<ContactsState['contacts']>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setContacts(INITIAL_STATE);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {contacts.map(contact => (
        <Contact
          key={contact.id}
          name={contact.name}
          email={contact.email}
          phone={contact.phone}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Contacts;
```

Pero quiero enviar directamente el objeto completo:

```
<Contact
    key={contact.id}
    contact={contact}
 />
```

Y que lo tome el componente hijo:

```
interface ContactProps {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
}

function Contact(props: ContactProps) {
  const { name, email, phone } = props;

  return (
    <div className="card card-body mb-3">
      <h4>{name}</h4>
      <ul className="list-group">
        <li className="list-group-item">Email: {email}</li>
        <li className="list-group-item">Phone: {phone}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes asignar el objeto `contact` como una prop dentro de la interfaz `ContactProps` y asignarle sus respectivos datatypes al `contact`. De esta manera Typescript sabe que recibirá un `contact` y sus datatypes.

```
interface ContactProps {
  contact: { 
    id?: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    phone: string;
  }
}
```

Puedes acceder al `contact`:

```
function Contact(props: ContactProps) {
  const { contact } = props;

  return (
    <div className="card card-body mb-3">
      <h4>{contact.name}</h4>
      <ul className="list-group">
        <li className="list-group-item">Email: {contact.email}</li>
        <li className="list-group-item">Phone: {contact.phone}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```